# Не могу вызвать команды после установки nestjs/cli

Tags: ubuntu, nestjs

После установки nestjs/cli в Ubuntu 22.04, не могу вызвать команды cli из терминала.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При вызове команды nest --help появляется данное сообщение о том что такой команды нет и то что якобы nest не установлен.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если у кого то возникала такая проблема, подскажите в чем может быть дело?

Answer (score 0):

Решил данную проблему с помощью вызова команды npx @nestjs/cli